# Using ArrayAdapter with Room

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-arrayadapter, android-room

How to refresh ArrayAdapter used in Fragment A, when data is inserted in Fragment B (DialogFragment if it helps) using Room?

I've tried:

- Calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in the DialogFragment class (I use a fullscreen dialog to insert,update and delete data from my database. No difference.
- Calling

`adapter.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
adapter.addAll(dbDAO.getList());
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged`

in my DialogFragment. This doesn't work either.

- I cannot add just that item in my ArrayAdapter because that would result in duplicate entries (one entry from the database and one from the adapter). This is also something I wouldn't want.

**More on my project**

I'm making a Timetable app on Android using Java. I'll have to explain how my project is structured to describe my problem.

My project has only one activity, which displays a single fragment (occupying all width and height). This fragment (TimetableFragment) has a Looping Viewpager (made by @siralam [here](https://github.com/siralam/LoopingViewPager)). As described in the LoopingViewPager's documentation, the item views are binded in the LoopingAdapter class within bindView() function.

Please let me know how to fix this. Also please let me know if there's anything else I should describe about my project/problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use Room Livedata, you don't need anything, when data change, livedata auto update in view

Comment: Livedata does seem like what I need but I really don't want to implement the RecyclerView Adapter class and the Viewmodel class and maybe the ViewHolder class with it. Any third-party libraries that can make my job easier?